# Get the records of last month in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to get the records of last month based on my database table [member] field `date_created`.

How can I use SQL to do this?

For clarification,
last month - 1/8/2009 to 31/8/2009

If today is 3/1/2010, I'll need to get the records of 1/12/2009 to 31/12/2009.

Comment: Does "last month" mean the "last 30 days", "all days in previous month" or "all days in current month"?

Comment: The best syntax also depends on if you're using SQL 2005 (or earlier) with a DATETIME field, or SQL 2008 with a DATE field.

Comment: What about `DATEDIFF(month, date_created, GETDATE()) = 1`? Wouldn't that work as well?

Answer (score 131, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM Member
WHERE DATEPART(m, date_created) = DATEPART(m, DATEADD(m, -1, getdate()))
AND DATEPART(yyyy, date_created) = DATEPART(yyyy, DATEADD(m, -1, getdate()))
```

You need to check the month and year.

Comment: in my case 
`SELECT * 
FROM Member
WHERE DATEPART(m, date_created) = DATEPART(m, DATEADD(m, -1, getdate()))
AND DATEPART(yy, date_created) = DATEPART(yy, DATEADD(m, -1, getdate()))`
works perfect

Comment: This approach will ignore any indexes on the table and do a table (or clustered index) scan every time it is run.  The larger the table gets the longer the query will take.

Comment: You must use yyyy instead of y

Comment: This should **not** be the accepted answer. Using `YEAR()`, `MONTH()`, `DATEPART()` or similar functions on the date being filtered eliminates any possibility that SQL server can optimize the query to use an index on that date. This bad practice should be strongly discouraged.

Answer (score 147):

All the existing (working) answers have one of two problems:

1. They will ignore indices on the column being searched
2. The will (potentially) select data that is not intended, silently corrupting your results.

**1. Ignored Indices:**

For the most part, when a column being searched has a function called on it (including implicitly, like for `CAST`), the optimizer must ignore indices on the column and search through every record.  Here's a quick example:

We're dealing with timestamps, and most RDBMSs tend to store this information as an increasing value of some sort, usually a `long` or `BIGINTEGER` count of milli-/nanoseconds.  The current time thus looks/is stored like this:

```
1402401635000000  -- 2014-06-10 12:00:35.000000 GMT
```

You don't see the 'Year' value (`'2014'`) in there, do you?  In fact, there's a fair bit of complicated math to translate back and forth.  So if you call any of the extraction/date part functions on the searched column, the server has to perform all that math just to figure out if you can include it in the results.  On small tables this isn't an issue, but as the percentage of rows selected decreases this becomes a larger and larger drain.  Then in this case, you're doing it a second time for asking about `MONTH`... well, you get the picture.

**2. Unintended data:**

Depending on the particular version of SQL Server, and column datatypes, using `BETWEEN` (or similar inclusive upper-bound ranges: `<=`) [can result in the wrong data being selected](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common).  Essentially, you potentially end up including data from midnight of the "next" day, or excluding some portion of the "current" day's records.

**What you *should* be doing:**

So we need a way that's safe for our data, and will use indices (if viable).  The correct way is then of the form:

```
WHERE date_created >= @startOfPreviousMonth AND date_created < @startOfCurrentMonth
```

Given that there's only one month, `@startOfPreviousMonth` can be easily substituted for/derived by:

```
DATEADD(month, -1, @startOfCurrentMonth)
```

If you need to derive the start-of-current-month in the server, you can do it via the following:

```
DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), 0)
```

A quick word of explanation here.  The initial `DATEDIFF(...)` will get the difference between the start of the current era (`0001-01-01` - AD, CE, whatever), essentially returning a large integer.  This is the count of months to the start of the *current* month.  We then add this number to the start of the era, which is at the start of the given month.

So your full script could/should look similar to the following:

```
DECLARE @startOfCurrentMonth DATETIME
SET @startOfCurrentMonth = DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), 0)

SELECT *
FROM Member
WHERE date_created >= DATEADD(month, -1, @startOfCurrentMonth)
      AND date_created < @startOfCurrentMonth
```

All date operations are thus only performed once, on one value; the optimizer is free to use indices, and no incorrect data will be included.

Comment: Very good answer, thank you! I'd like to suggest you to extract "DATEADD(month, -1, @startOfCurrentMonth)" to another variable, perhaps "@startOfLastMonth", in order to avoid the optimizer doing this calculation for every iteration. I tryed to collaborate editing this answer by myself, but its edit queue if full.

Comment: @YorgaBabuscan - If by "iteration" you mean "comparison for row", the calculation is recognized by the optimizer to be operating on a constant value, and is only calculated once.  If it was calculated for each row, it wouldn't be able to use an index for the lower bound comparison at all, which would be very detrimental.

Comment: With SQL Server 2022 and later, the `DATETRUNC()` function can be used to simplify the calculation. The resulting code would be `DECLARE @startOfCurrentMonth DATETIME = DATETRUNC(month, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)`, `DECLARE @startOfPreviousMonth DATETIME = DATEADD(month, -1, @startOfCurrentMonth)`, and `WHERE date_created >= @startOfPreviousMonth AND date_created < @startOfCurrentMonth`. *(And just as a reminder to the reader, `<` must be used instead of `<=` because the end-date is **exclusive**. This is also why `BETWEEN` should not be used.)*

Answer (score 13):

Add the options which have been provided so far won't use your indexes at all.

Something like this will do the trick, and make use of an index on the table (if one exists).

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME, @EndDate DATETIME
SET @StartDate = dateadd(mm, -1, getdate())
SET @StartDate = dateadd(dd, datepart(dd, getdate())*-1, @StartDate)
SET @EndDate = dateadd(mm, 1, @StartDate)

SELECT *
FROM Member
WHERE date_created BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
```

Comment: Sorry to downvote, but it doesn't work: Try '12/31/2013 11:59' for a counterexample (returns rows between '2013-10-30 11:59:00.000' and '2013-11-30 11:59:00.000' on SQL Server).

Comment: getdate() give you current time. I think you should take time from 12:00 AM (starting of day). @Rokas answer is correct. Print start time and end time if you want to see.

Comment: This solution should **not** be used for two reasons. The `@StartDate` and `@EndDate` calculations do not eliminate the time component. Even if they did, the use of `BETWEEN` would incorrectly include midnight (00:00:00) of the date following the intended date range.

Answer (score 12):

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME, @EndDate DATETIME
SET @StartDate = DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm,0,getdate())-1, 0)
SET @EndDate = DATEADD(mm, 1, @StartDate)

SELECT *
FROM Member
WHERE date_created BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
```

An upgrade to mrdenny's solution, this way you get exactly last month from YYYY-MM-01

Comment: `BETWEEN` should not be used because it would incorrectly include midnight (00:00:00) of the date following the intended date range. Instead, the test should be written as `WHERE date_created >= @StartDate AND date_created < @EndDate`. Note the use of `<` instead of `<=`.

Answer (score 5):

Last month consider as till last day of the month.
31/01/2016 here last day of the month would be 31 Jan. which is not similar to last 30 days.

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(DAY,-DAY(GETDATE()),GETDATE()))
```

Answer (score 2):

SQL query to get record of the present month only

```
SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER
WHERE MONTH(DATE) = MONTH(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AND YEAR(DATE) = YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

Comment: Using YEAR(), MONTH(), DATEPART() or similar functions on the date being filtered eliminates any possibility that SQL server can optimize the query to use an index on that date. This bad practice should be strongly discouraged.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM Member WHERE month(date_created) = month(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH);
```

Comment: Code dumps do not make for good answers. You should explain how and why this solves their problem. I recommend reading, [How do I write a good answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7656/how-do-i-write-a-good-answer-to-a-question)

Comment: "WHERE myDate > (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)" allowed me to get all of the records for myDate within the past month, thanks for the tip

Comment: Using YEAR(), MONTH(), DATEPART() or similar functions on the date being filtered eliminates any possibility that SQL server can optimize the query to use an index on that date. This bad practice should be strongly discouraged.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is using the [DATEPART](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx) function:

```
select field1, field2, fieldN from TABLE where DATEPART(month, date_created) = 4 
and DATEPART(year, date_created) = 2009
```

will return all dates in april. For last month (ie, previous to current month) you can use [GETDATE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188383.aspx) and [DATEADD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) as well:

```
select field1, field2, fieldN from TABLE where DATEPART(month, date_created) 
= (DATEPART(month, GETDATE()) - 1) and 
DATEPART(year, date_created) = DATEPART(year, DATEADD(m, -1, GETDATE()))
```

Comment: This approach will ignore any indexes on the table and do a table (or clustered index) scan every time it is run. The larger the table gets the longer the query will take.

Comment: Using YEAR(), MONTH(), DATEPART() or similar functions on the date being filtered eliminates any possibility that SQL server can optimize the query to use an index on that date. This bad practice should be strongly discouraged.

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @PrevMonth as nvarchar(256)

SELECT @PrevMonth = DateName( month,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, getdate()) - 1, 0)) + 
   '-' + substring(DateName( Year, getDate() ) ,3,4)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from [member] where DatePart("m", date_created) = DatePart("m", DateAdd("m", -1, getdate())) AND DatePart("yyyy", date_created) = DatePart("yyyy", DateAdd("m", -1, getdate()))
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE 
    date_created >= DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 31, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), 0)
    AND date_created < DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), 0)
```

Comment: A little bit of explanation?

Answer (score 0):

I'm from Oracle env and I would do it like this in Oracle:

```
select * from table
where trunc(somedatefield, 'MONTH') =
trunc(sysdate -INTERVAL '0-1' YEAR TO MONTH, 'MONTH')
```

Idea: I'm running a scheduled report of previous month (from day 1 to the last day of the month, not windowed). This could be index unfriendly, but Oracle has fast date handling anyways.
Is there a similar simple and short way in MS SQL? The answer comparing year and month separately seems silly to Oracle folks.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the last month records with this query

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.member d 
WHERE  CONVERT(DATE, date_created,101)>=CONVERT(DATE,DATEADD(m, datediff(m, 0, current_timestamp)-1, 0)) 
and CONVERT(DATE, date_created,101) < CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(m, datediff(m, 0, current_timestamp)-1, 0),101)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the accepted solution is very index friendly
I use the following lines instead

```
select * from dbtable where the_date >= convert(varchar(10),DATEADD(m, -1, dateadd(d, - datepart(dd, GETDATE())+1, GETDATE())),120) and the_date <= dateadd(ms, -3, convert(varchar(10),DATEADD(m, 0, dateadd(d, - datepart(dd, GETDATE())+1, GETDATE())),120));
```

Or simply (this is the best).

```
select * from dbtable where the_date >= convert(varchar(10),DATEADD(m, -1, dateadd(d, - datepart(dd, GETDATE())+1, GETDATE())),120) and the_date < SELECT convert(varchar(10),DATEADD(m, -1, dateadd(d, - datepart(dd, GETDATE())+1, GETDATE())),120);
```

Some help

```
-- Get the first of last month
SELECT convert(varchar(10),DATEADD(m, -1, dateadd(d, - datepart(dd, GETDATE())+1, GETDATE())),120);
-- Get the first of current month
SELECT convert(varchar(10),DATEADD(m, -1, dateadd(d, - datepart(dd, GETDATE())+1, GETDATE())),120);
--Get the last of last month except the last 3milli seconds. (3miliseconds being used as SQL express otherwise round it up to the full second (SERIUSLY MS)
SELECT dateadd(ms, -3, convert(varchar(10),DATEADD(m, 0, dateadd(d, - datepart(dd, GETDATE())+1, GETDATE())),120));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did so I could put it in a view:

```
ALTER view [dbo].[MyView] as

with justdate as (
select getdate() as rightnow
)
, inputs as (
select dateadd(day, 1, EOMONTH(jd.rightnow, -2)) as FirstOfLastMonth
      ,dateadd(day, 1, EOMONTH(jd.rightnow, -1)) as FirstOfThisMonth
  from justdate jd
)
SELECT TOP 10000
       [SomeColumn]
      ,[CreatedTime]
  from inputs i
  join [dbo].[SomeTable]
    on createdtime >= i.FirstOfLastMonth
   and createdtime < i.FirstOfThisMonth
 order by createdtime
;
```

Note that I intentionally ran `getdate()` once.

Answer (score -1):

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME, @EndDate DATETIME    
SET @StartDate = DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, getdate()) - 1, 0)    
SET @EndDate = dateadd(dd, -1, DATEADD(mm, 1, @StartDate))

SELECT * FROM Member WHERE date_created BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
```

and another upgrade to mrdenny's solution.
It gives the exact last day of the previous month as well.

Answer (score -2):

In Sql server for last one month:

```
select * from tablename 
where order_date > DateAdd(WEEK, -1, GETDATE()+1) and order_date<=GETDATE()
```

Comment: Should perhaps `WEEK` be `MONTH` ?

Answer (score -2):

```
DECLARE @curDate INT = datepart( Month,GETDATE())
IF (@curDate = 1)
    BEGIN
        select * from Featured_Deal
        where datepart( Month,Created_Date)=12 AND datepart(Year,Created_Date) = (datepart(Year,GETDATE())-1)

    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        select * from Featured_Deal
        where datepart( Month,Created_Date)=(datepart( Month,GETDATE())-1) AND datepart(Year,Created_Date) = datepart(Year,GETDATE())

    END
```

Answer (score -2):

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME, @EndDate DATETIME
SET @StartDate = dateadd(mm, -1, getdate())
SET @StartDate = dateadd(dd, datepart(dd, getdate())*-1, @StartDate)
SET @EndDate = dateadd(mm, 1, @StartDate)
set @StartDate = DATEADD(dd, 1 , @StartDate)
```

Answer (score -2):

The way I fixed similar issue was by adding Month to my **SELECT** portion

```
Month DATEADD(day,Created_Date,'1971/12/31') As Month
```

and than I added **WHERE** statement

```
Month DATEADD(day,Created_Date,'1971/12/31') = month(getdate())-1
```

Answer (score -2):

***If you are looking for last month so try this,***

```
SELECT
FROM  #emp 
WHERE DATEDIFF(MONTH,CREATEDDATE,GETDATE()) = 1
```

***If you are looking for last month so try this,***

```
SELECT
FROM #emp
WHERE DATEDIFF(day,CREATEDDATE,GETDATE()) between 1 and 30
```

Comment: Please read the previous answers to see why this wouldn't work and\or not the correct way to do it before people downvoting it. And maybe you would like to remove your reply.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. When answering a question that already has many answers (17!), please be sure to add some additional insight into why the hastily composed response you're providing is substantive and not simply echoing what's already been vetted by the original poster. This is especially important in "code-only" answers like yours.

Answer (score -2):

A simple query which works for me is:

select * from table where DATEADD(month, 1,DATEFIELD) >= getdate()

Answer (score -2):

If you are looking for previous month data:

```
date(date_created)>=date_sub(date_format(curdate(),"%Y-%m-01"),interval 1 month) and 
date(date_created)<=date_sub(date_format(curdate(),'%Y-%m-01'),interval 1 day)
```

This will also work when the year changes. It will also work on MySQL.