# SQL query to list the latest rows for every week

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, group-by

In SQL Server, I have the following data and I want to get the latest row for every week.

I have the following table. The `WW` (week number of the date) column doesn't exist, just the date, I put it there to explain better the purpose of the query.

```
Number  Date          WW
392     2012-07-23    30
439     2012-07-24    30
735     2012-07-25    30
882     2012-07-26    30 *
193     2012-07-30    31
412     2012-07-31    31   
425     2012-08-01    31
748     2012-08-02    31
711     2012-08-03    31 *
757     2012-08-07    32
113     2012-08-08    32 *
444     2012-08-15    33 *
```

The desired result of the query should be

```
882     30 
711     31 
113     32 
444     33
```

Basically what I want to get is the latest row of every week. I have found examples like this [Get the records of last month in SQL server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424999/get-the-records-of-last-month-in-sql-server)
to find just the latest one, but I don't know how to extend them to get the list of results for every week. The rows can be stored in any date, for example maybe in a week there are no results, or in a week there are 5 rows and the next week 10 rows. I would really appreciate some hints for this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to use something like this:

```
select t1.number, t2.ww
from yourtable t1
inner join
(
    select max(date) mxdate, datepart(week, [Date]) ww
    from yourtable 
    group by datepart(week, [Date])
) t2
    on t1.date = t2.mxdate
    and datepart(week, t1.[Date]) = t2.ww;
```

Or you can use `CTE`:

```
;with cte as
(
  select number, datepart(week, [Date]) ww,
    row_number() over(partition by datepart(week, [Date]) 
                      order by date desc) rn
  from yourtable
)
select number, ww
from cte
where rn = 1
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9b013/1)

If you use the `MAX()` version of this and you have two numbers with the same date, then you will return two records. Using the `row_number()` version will only return one record that meets the criteria due to applying the row_number filter  (See [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/344de/1))

Comment: As the question says WW is not a real column.  You should probably replace it by `datepart(week, [Date])`

Comment: @Andomar obviously I missed that. Thanks

Comment: Beat me to the punch - This should work for you although I have notice some funny behaviour depending on if you are doing Monday-Sunday as your weeks EG: `2012-10-01 - 111` (Yesterday), `2012-10-07 - 222` (Sunday) I would expect week 222 for that week instead it does 111 and then 222 for example treating Sunday as the start of the week?

Comment: @ConradFrix added details and a demo of the two queries showing the difference.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using sql server you can do this:

```
declare @test table(Number int, Date datetime, WW int);

INSERT INTO @test
    (Number, Date, WW)
VALUES
    (392, '2012-07-22 17:00:00', 30),
    (439, '2012-07-23 17:00:00', 30),
    (735, '2012-07-24 17:00:00', 30),
    (882, '2012-07-25 17:00:00', 30),
    (193, '2012-07-29 17:00:00', 31),
    (412, '2012-07-30 17:00:00', 31),
    (425, '2012-07-31 17:00:00', 31),
    (748, '2012-08-01 17:00:00', 31),
    (711, '2012-08-05 17:00:00', 31),
    (757, '2012-08-06 17:00:00', 32),
    (113, '2012-08-07 17:00:00', 32),
    (444, '2012-08-14 17:00:00', 33)

SELECT * FROM (
select number, date, ww,
row_number() over (partition by ww order by date desc) rn
from @test) v
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with a correlated sub-query as shown below:

```
SELECT number, [date]
FROM tablename T
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM tablename
    WHERE DATEPART(wk, [date]) = DATEPART(wk, T.[date])
        AND date > T.[date]
)
```

Note this does not return 2012-08-06 as I believe this is actually in the 32nd week of the  year http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=6th+August+2012