# How to add check for January in SQL statement

Tags: sql

I'm creating a report using SQL to pull logged labor hours from our labor database for the previous month. I have it working great, but need to add logic to prevent it from breaking when it runs in January. I've tried adding If/Then statements and CASE logic, but I don't know if I'm just not doing it right, or if our system can't process it. Here's the snippet that pulls the date range:

```
SELECT
  ...
FROM
  ...
WHERE
  ...
   AND
YEAR(ENTERDATE) = YEAR(current date) AND MONTH(ENTERDATE) = (MONTH(current date)-1)
```

Comment: What you're asking is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424999/get-the-records-of-last-month-in-sql-server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use AND as a barrier like this. In January, the second clause will be executed instead of the first one:

```
SELECT
  ...
FROM
  ...
WHERE
  ...
  AND
  (
    (
      (MONTH(current date) > 1) AND
      (YEAR(ENTERDATE) = YEAR(current date) AND MONTH(ENTERDATE) = (MONTH(current date)-1))
      -- this one gets used from Feb-Dec
    )
    OR
    (
      (MONTH(current date) = 1) AND
      (YEAR(ENTERDATE) = YEAR(current date) - 1 AND MONTH(ENTERDATE) = 12)
      -- alternatively, in Jan only this one gets used
    )
  )
```

Comment: This doesn't throw any errors and is working for this month. Is there an easy way to test this before January?

Comment: Yeah. Replace all 3 instances of `MONTH(current date)` with a hardcoded `1`

Answer (score 1):

If your report is always going to be for the previous month, then I think the simplest idea is to declare the year and month of the previous month and then reference those in the Where clause. For example:

```
Declare LastMo_Month Integer = MONTH(DATEADD(MONTH,-1,getdate()));
Declare LastMo_Year Integer = YEAR(DATEADD(MONTH,-1,getdate()));

Select ...

Where MONTH(EnterDate) = @LastMo_Month
    and YEAR(EnterDate) = @LastMo_Year
```

You could even take it a step further and allow the report to be created for any number of months ago:

```
Declare Delay Integer = -1;
Declare LastMo_Month Integer = MONTH(DATEADD(MONTH,@Delay,getdate()));
Declare LastMo_Year Integer = YEAR(DATEADD(MONTH,@Delay,getdate()));

Select ...

Where MONTH(EnterDate) = @LastMo_Month
    and YEAR(EnterDate) = @LastMo_Year
```

Hope this helps.

PS - This is my first answer on StackOverflow, so sorry if the formatting isn't right!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the previous month and year to your SELECT statement:

```
SELECT
    ...
    ,CASE MONTH(current date)
        WHEN 1 THEN 12
        ELSE MONTH(current date)-1
    END AS previous_month
    ,CASE MONTH(current date)
        WHEN 1 THEN YEAR(current date)-1
        ELSE YEAR(current date)
    END AS previous_year
FROM
    ...
WHERE
    ...
    AND YEAR(ENTERDATE) = previous_year
    AND MONTH(ENTERDATE) = previous_month
```

This should allow you to set the value before the `WHERE` comparison. This should be the most performant way to perform this procedure, as it avoids creating two entirely separate clauses or using `OR`.

Comment: That only helps with the month, which is/should be working. The problem I need to fix, is that in its current state, the report in January 2014 will try and pull labor report for December of 2014 instead of 2013.

Comment: i know u already selected an answer, but while it will work fine it is definitely not the most efficient way to handle the query. i've updated to include year components, which should give you what you want in a much more performant way.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(month(getdate()) = 1)
begin
        your jan logic
end
else
begin
        your logic
end
```

The above answer with the Case is ok, but running a CASE on a huge result set would be pretty costly

Comment: getdate() is not a recognized function in our database =/

Comment: GETDATE() is MySQL. Question is for SQL Server

Comment: getdate() works fine in SQL server not sure whats up

Answer (score 0):

Which Dialect of SQL are you speaking?

As opposed to doing it all with case statements,  just use the built it date / time functions to subtract a month from the current date, which should handle crossing year boundaries.

TransACT

```
  WHERE
   YEAR(ENTERDATE) = year(dateadd(MONTH,-1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))
   AND MONTH(ENTERDATE) = month(dateadd(MONTH,-1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))
```

Mysql

```
 WHERE
   YEAR(ENTERDATE) = YEAR(date_sub(curdate(),INTERVAL 1 MONTH))
   AND MONTH(ENTERDATE) = MONTH(date_sub(curdate(),INTERVAL 1 MONTH) )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE
...
AND
DATEPART(yy,ENTERDATE) = DATEPART(yy,DATEADD(m,-1,ENTERDATE))
AND DATEPART(m,ENTERDATE) = DATEPART(m,DATEADD(m,-1,ENTERDATE))
```