# get last previous month records

Tags: sql, sql-server

sql 2005 server

get previous month records

```
Date        product
24-05-2014  ball
25-05-2014  bat
01-06-2014  hat
```

i need

```
Date        Product
24-05-2014  ball
25-05-2014  bat

declare @ex datetime
set @ex '06-01-2014'

select * from tabl where DATENAME(m,DATEADD(m,0,Date)) =DATENAME(m, DATEADD(m,0, @ex))- it works
select * from tabl where DATENAME(m,DATEADD(m,0,Date)) =DATENAME(m, DATEADD(m,-1,@ex))-not works
```

Comment: @user3426968 I'm not sure that will work, because this is for SQL Server 2005, and that function doesn't exist.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/1424999/1741542

Comment: This code works for me, how are you putting the dates into your temp table?  Try just running SELECT DATENAME(m,DATEADD(m,0,ProdDate)) FROM tabl and see what the datenames are coming out as?

Comment: DATENAME(m,DATEADD(m,0,ProdDate)) & DATENAME(m,DATEADD(m,+1,ProdDate)) both works but DATENAME(m,DATEADD(m,-1,ProdDate))does not work

Comment: SqlFiddle link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ae57e/4   Not sure what error you are getting on your side.

Comment: Are you using "Date" for a column name? It is a reserved word for a sql type, maybe confusion from that?

Comment: i am using ExpiryDate no problem with that

Comment: I have a strong feeling that your dates aren't being interpreted the way you think they are, or the way you want them to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My sample code (tested on 2008). I don't know are YEAR and MOTH function in 2005 if not you need to use some string function to extract date / month part from datetime converted to string

```
declare @ex datetime = '2014-01-01'
declare @prev_year int
declare @prev_month int

set @prev_year = year(dateadd(month, -1, @ex))
set @prev_month = month(dateadd(month, -1, @ex))

select * from tabl 
where year(Date) = @prev_year and month(Date) = @prev_month
```

Comment: it does'nt work in sql2005

Answer (score 0):

You're using `dd-MM-yyyy` format for your dates, which is a `varchar` in SQL Server.
Therefor, you must use `CONVERT` :

```
declare @ex varchar(10)
set @ex = '06-01-2014'

SELECT  DATENAME(m,DATEADD(m,0,GETDATE())),

 DATENAME(m, DATEADD(m,-1,CONVERT(date, @ex, 103)));
```

This yields results:

`June | May`

I think you can figure out your solution from here.

Note: If you use `declare @ex datetime` , your results will yield `June | December`