# How to get only a particular month's data in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get only previous sixth month's data form the query.

i.e I have to group by only the previous sixth months.

Suppose current month is June then I only want January's data & also I don't want all the previous month other than January

Can anyone help me for this

```
SELECT 
   so_date
FROM 
   RS_Sells_Invoice_Info_Master SIIM
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
   RS_Sell_Order_Master AS SM ON SM.sell_order_no = SIIM.sell_order_no
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
   RS_Sell_Order_Mapping AS SOM ON SOM.sell_order_no = SIIM.sell_order_no AND SIIM.product_id = SOM.product_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
   RS_Inventory_Master AS IM ON IM.product_id = SIIM.product_id
where 
   so_date between CAST(DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, so_date)-5, 0)AS DATE) and CAST(DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, so_date)-4, 0)AS DATE)
```

Comment: "The previous six months" is not the same as "only want January's data". Which do you want - all data since January, all data **from** January (and January only), or the "previous six months" which may have multiple interpretations (the current calendar month and 5 prior, the 6 calendar months prior to the current one, today's date minus 6 months to the day, other)?

Comment: Duplicate, of at least [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424999/get-the-records-of-last-month-in-sql-server), although none of the existing answers are ideal (now adding better answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get all the data for a specific month (6 months ago) use the following where clause,
You need to compare month and year, to ensure you get the correct month ie if the current month is May you want December from the previous year.

```
  where 
          datepart(Month, [so_date]) = datepart(Month, dateadd(month, -6,getdate())) 
       and
          datepart(Year, [so_date]) = datepart(year, dateadd(month, -6,getdate()))
```

Comment: This solution cannot use an index and will be unnecessarily slow on large tables.

Comment: Sorry,I did not got you

Answer (score 1):

> Suppose current month is June then I only want January's data

This would work

```
WHERE 
  so_date >= DATEADD(mm, -6, LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 120), 8) + '01')
  AND
  so_date <  DATEADD(mm, -5, LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 120), 8) + '01')
```

The `LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 120), 8) + '01'` gives you the start of the current month in `YYYY-MM-DD` format. The rest is straight-forward.

Comment: First: I don't think we're close enough for you to call me "dude". Second: *"this is not working"* is anything but an error description.

Comment: Okay Sir thak you for your valuable time I got the solution

Comment: I'd avoid [`BETWEEN` on SQL Server](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common).  Or when trying to query continuous-range types on **any** RDBMS, actually.

Comment: @Clockwork Hm, interesting read. I'm not sure if I follow the premise though. The author of the post does some stupid things and then complains that the results are unexpected. Like `WHERE  CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME, OrderDate) BETWEEN '20110701' AND '20110731';` - I mean, WTF? Who in their right mind would do that? I do agree with the *"inclusive range"* argument and will change my query accordingly.

Comment: @Tomalak - In context, the author is demonstrating what happens if either the actual stored type changes, or if somebody is trying to make their current query "safe" via casting (never mind the fact that would probably cause indices to be ignored too).  Personally I think `BETWEEN` is one of those "evil" things that should be removed from the standard (you want an inclusive range, you can explicitly ask for it, but it's only safe for integer types...).

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse I understand what the author is trying to say, but if you use your tools wrong, then the results won't be what you might expect. Using *that* as an argument against - in this case - `BETWEEN` is weak. But the blog post does have a point. *(As far as I am concerned, `BETWEEN` should represent the `[from_date,to_date[` range, that it represents `[from_date,to_date]` is unfortunate.)*

Comment: @Tomalak - But then people are going to be looking at their results funny(ier) if they're using it for negative numbers (the exclusive bound is the _lower_ one - `>` - in that case).

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse You're right. I think I'll be a lot more sensitive to `BETWEEN` issues from now on, thank you. :)

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse BTW your answer in the other thread shows a problem with SO in general: Late, good answers rarely receive the attention they deserve. I nudged the OP to mark your answer as accepted instead.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the example, you use **DateAdd** function to minus the sixmonth and compare with **Between** functionality

```
Declare @t table (name varchar(50), createddate datetime)

Insert into @t values('ajay', GETDATE()-50 ),('ajay1', '2014-03-10' ),('ajay2', '2013-12-09' ),('ajay3', '2013-11-10' )
declare @currentdate datetime = getdate() , @sixmontholddate datetime = dateadd( MONTH, -6,getdate())

select @currentdate , @sixmontholddate

select  * from @t

select * from @t where createddate between dateadd( MONTH, -6,getdate()) and GETDATE()
```

Comment: This is [SQL Server](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common), let's not.  Heck, you shouldn't be trying this with continuous-range types on any server.