# How to use Date range in the WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to modify my `Where` clause in my `SQL Server Query` below so that it would select ALL records from the previous month.

Example: if I run the query on 20 Feb, it should extract data for 1 Jan to 31 Jan

I have tried using the following but as you may notice, it picks up the records a month back from the day of execution.

```
WHERE date_col >= cast(dateadd(Month, -1, getdate()) as date) and
      date_col <= cast(getdate() as date)
```

Comment: I don't have a local install of SQL to bang this out against, but basically you have to work out what the first day of the current month is, then get the records that fall between -1 month of that date and that date. `dateadd(day, -1 * datepart(day, getdate()), getdate())` or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TO get the last and first day of previous month :

```
SELECT DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, DATEADD(MONTH,-1,GETDATE())), 0) AS First_Day_Of_Last_Month
       ,DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,GETDATE()),0))       AS Last_day_Of_Last_Month
```

### Result:

```
╔═════════════════════════╦═════════════════════════╗
║ First_Day_Of_Last_Month ║ Last_day_Of_Last_Month  ║
╠═════════════════════════╬═════════════════════════╣
║ 2014-05-01 00:00:00.000 ║ 2014-05-31 23:59:59.000 ║
╚═════════════════════════╩═════════════════════════╝
```

**Your Query**

```
WHERE date_col >= DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, DATEADD(MONTH,-1,GETDATE())), 0)
  AND date_col <= DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,GETDATE()),0))
```

Comment: Not to be nit-picky, but my answer is more accurate. Your answer leaves off a second out of the possible date frame. If anything, I'd highly recommend that you change your DATEADD(s, -1...) to subtract a single nanosecond DATEADD(ns, -1...). This may seem insignificant, but not when you can't fully reconcile the data by hand and get the same answer.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not claiming this is the best way, but it should work:

```
SELECT * from YourTable
WHERE  DATEPART(Month, date_col) = (DATEPART(Month,GETDATE()) - 1)
AND    DATEPART(Year, date_col) = DATEPART(Year,DATEADD(Month, -1, GETDATE()))
```

Comment: This is the easiest way of doing this but not the best as this  `DATEPART` function on column will make this query Non-Sargble .

Comment: You're right. That will definitely have an effect, however it will include all of the data.

Answer (score 2):

**Sql Server 2012 and Later**

EOMONTH looks like it may be a useful function in this case.
EOMONTH(getdate(), -1) is the end of last month.
EOMONTH(getdate(), -2) is the end of the month before.

Try something like

```
WHERE date_col >= cast(EOMONTH(getdate(), -1) as date) and date_col <=
cast(EOMONTH(getdate(),-2) as date);
```

Comment: `EOMONTH` only works in newer versions of SQL Server, but it is the right way to do this now.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want all records from the previous month, you could just compare the month and year parts of the current date and the `date_col` values, like so:

```
select * 
from yourtable
where 
(month(date_col) = month(getdate()) - 1
and year(date_col) = year(getdate()) 
and month(getdate()) <> 1)
or
(month(date_col) = 12
 and year(date_col) = year(getdate()) - 1
 and month(getdate()) = 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

This query also work as already ask by some one and good rating of answer too.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Member
WHERE DATEPART(m, date_created) = DATEPART(m, DATEADD(m, -1, getdate()))
AND DATEPART(yyyy, date_created) = DATEPART(yyyy, DATEADD(m, -1, getdate()))
```

[Get the records of last month in SQL server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424999/get-the-records-of-last-month-in-sql-server)