# How to add new variable in Opencart product controller?

Tags: php, variables, opencart

I stuck with an Opencart issue, it is old version 1.5.6.4.
I want to show the lowest special price on the product page.

Firstly I created a function in the model with the SQL query:

```
public function getSpecialPriceMin($product_id) {
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT MIN(price) FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_special WHERE product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "'");
return $query->row;
}
```

Then I tried to save the result in a variable in the product controller (without success as I am receiving an error message undefined variable):

```
$data['myVariable'] = $this->model_catalog_product->getSpecialPriceMin($product_id);
```

And then I try to echo the variable on the product page:

```
<?php echo $myVariable; ?>
```

I would appreciate any help. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use OC 1.5.x.x version you should use:
in model file:

```
public function getSpecialPriceMin($product_id) {
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT MIN(price) AS min_price FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_special WHERE product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "'");
return $query->row;
}
```

Controller:

```
$query = $this->model_catalog_product->getSpecialPriceMin($product_id);
$this->data['myVariable'] = $query['min_price'];
```

And then  you can  to echo the variable on product page:

```
<?php echo $myVariable; ?>
```

Comment: Hello and thank you for your answer. I tried the $this keyword and in this case I am getting another message Notice: Array to string conversion.

Comment: My sql query should result only a single value (the minimum special price), is it necessary to store this value in an array?

Comment: I have edited my answer. please try again.

Comment: Super, thank you it works. I am a beginner in sql, could you please help me understand the min_price you used is an alias?

Comment: One more thing I want to accomplish. I want to query the minimum price 1 month minus current date. I tried to extend my query with this: `AND date_end > DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 MONTH)` but I get this error message: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'MONTH' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ')' could you help me how to use the MONTH function properly in this case? Thank you

Comment: Regarding alias `min_price` you can use what you want. Regarding the next question you should to check sql syntax in your query. An error prompts you what is wrong...You can read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424999/get-the-records-of-last-month-in-sql-server
And if my answer was useful you can mark it as useful.