# DATEADD to return data in the last 3 months but I want full month of data

Tags: sql, sql-server

So my query aims to grab all data in the last 3 months, but only returns data when it is a full month.
I have tried:

```
WHERE Created_Date >  DATEADD(MONTH, -3, GETDATE())
```

or

```
WHERE Created_Date >  DATEADD(DAY, -90, GETDATE())
```

Both ways return the data in the last 3 months starting from current date. But the thing is, since my query wants to get aggregated data, so if today is 8th Aug, 3 months dating back means May has not got the full month of data (from 1st to 31st), so the aggregated data is not fully reported in the results. Does this make sense?

Is there any other way to return the full month data?

I know that we can use @startOfCurrentMonth [like in here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424999/get-the-records-of-last-month-in-sql-server) but this is 3 months we are aiming to get.

Comment: What RDMS you're using?

Comment: @kurniadi445 I use MS SQL Server

Comment: Did you try `DATEADD(MONTH, -3, @startOfCurrentMonth`? Also see [Simplify date period calculations in SQL Server](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6088/simplify-date-period-calculations-in-sql-server/?utm_source=AaronBertrand).

Answer (score 2):

To get the days of the current month plus three full months back, simply subtract four months and get that month's last day. Then take any dates after that day.

```
WHERE created_date > EOMONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, -4, GETDATE()))
```

If created_date is a misnomer and contains datetimes instead of dates, add a day and include that:

```
WHERE created_date >= DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(GETDATE(), -4)))
```

Comment: or `eomonth(getdate(), -4)`

Comment: @lptr: Thank you for sharing this information. I didn't know that `EOMONTH` has an optional parameter to add/subtract months.

Comment: Hi no it does not return the full month data for April for me! it is still less than full month of records. It does not work this way

Comment: It should not select April at all. `EOMONTH(GETDATE(), -4)` returns '2022-04-30', so creation dates after that should start with '2022-05-01'. If you are still getting April, this means that your column is incorrectly named and is not containing dates, but datetimes/timestamps. In that case add a day and include it. I've updated my answer with such a solution. I suggest you rename the column in your table then, too, to avoid incorrect queries caused by the misnomer.

Comment: `>= DATEADD(DAY` is the better and more future-proof pattern in all cases, even if the column is currently `date` as you assumed. Unfortunately a date suffix very rarely has an explicit tie to the data type, especially if it changes later (unlikely to be renamed), and Microsoft sets many bad examples here (look at all the _date columns in sys.objects, sys.databases, etc).

Comment: In SQL Server 2022 you can use `>= DATETRUNC(month, EOMONTH(GETDATE(), -3))` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datetrunc-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16